# Всё ли нормально? Ставятся ли запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Люди, при виде дерева, обретали силу.

Answer (score 1):

Разумеется, "смысловое выделение" можно прилепить почти к чему угодно, было бы желание. Но если ничего не выдумывать, не высасывать из пальца, то запятые не ставятся. Если это школьный пример, то запятые, конечно, ошибка, и довольно грубая.

P.S. Приведенные примеры с авторской пунктуацией совершенно неубедительны. Подчёркиваю: тем более, если это школьное задание.

Answer (score 0):

Запятые возможны.

Обстоятельства, выраженные существительными в формах косвенных надежей с предлогами, обособляются для попутного пояснения или смыслового выделения. **Такое обособление факультативно:**

> Осталась только серебристая пыль. Но, когда девки, по глупости, через несколько дней стерли ее, с тетей Тоней сделалась истерика (Бун.); Филин, с шорохом, задевая крыльями солому, срывался с крыши (Бун.); И Наташка, с болезненным удивлением, глядела на разряженный народ (Бун.); В полной тьме, среди ночи, подвезли Медею к железнодорожному вокзалу (Улиц.); Ночью, против окрепшего ветра, отряд шел в порт на посадку (Плат.); За одиннадцать лет, при ежедневной езде, наверно, было пережито немало интересных приключений (Ч.).

См.: Академический справочник.

Comment: То есть ошибкой это не считается?

Comment: Нет, не считается!

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь)

Answer (score 0):

Люди, при виде дерева, обретали силу.

**Обособление факультативное, но  решение зависит от контекста.** Без него сложно представить ситуацию, при которой этот обстоятельственный оборот обособляется со значением попутного объяснения или смыслового выделения.